# make: *** [all] Error 2 while make

Tags: linux, make, gnu, configure

Trying to Build and Install the Apache Thrift compiler and libraries -

`./configure && make`

But then I get make error which I don't seem to understand where it fails...

```
thrift 0.9.3

Building C++ Library ......... : no
Building C (GLib) Library .... : no
Building Java Library ........ : no
Building C# Library .......... : no
Building Python Library ...... : no
Building Ruby Library ........ : no
Building Haxe Library ........ : no
Building Haskell Library ..... : no
Building Perl Library ........ : no
Building PHP Library ......... : no
Building Erlang Library ...... : no
Building Go Library .......... : no
Building D Library ........... : no
Building NodeJS Library ...... : no
Building Lua Library ......... : no

If something is missing that you think should be present,
please skim the output of configure to find the missing
component.  Details are present in config.log.
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/c/University/InternetOfThings/thrift-0.9.3'
Making all in compiler/cpp
make[2]: Entering directory '/c/University/InternetOfThings/thrift-0.9.3/compile                                                                                                                                                 r/cpp'
make  all-am
make[3]: Entering directory '/c/University/InternetOfThings/thrift-0.9.3/compile                                                                                                                                                 r/cpp'
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -I../../lib/cpp/src/thrift  -I./src  -Wall -Wno-                                                                                                                                                 sign-compare -Wno-unused -g -O2 -std=c++11 -MT src/libparse_a-thrifty.o -MD -MP                                                                                                                                                  -MF src/.deps/libparse_a-thrifty.Tpo -c -o src/libparse_a-thrifty.o `test -f 'sr                                                                                                                                                 c/thrifty.cc' || echo './'`src/thrifty.cc
src/thrifty.yy: In function 'int yyparse()':
src/thrifty.yy:1309:30: error: 'strdup' was not declared in this scope
Makefile:912: recipe for target 'src/libparse_a-thrifty.o' failed
make[3]: *** [src/libparse_a-thrifty.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/c/University/InternetOfThings/thrift-0.9.3/compiler                                                                                                                                                 /cpp'
Makefile:588: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/c/University/InternetOfThings/thrift-0.9.3/compiler                                                                                                                                                 /cpp'
Makefile:609: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/c/University/InternetOfThings/thrift-0.9.3'
Makefile:530: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @countermode this is 100% on topic! The OP hasn't written this software, they are trying to install it. And that error is not very helpful if you're not a C programmer. This is a user asking for help installing software in their Linux machine, and so is on topic.

Answer (score 3):

This is the relevant error:

```
src/thrifty.yy: In function 'int yyparse()':
src/thrifty.yy:1309:30: error: 'strdup' was not declared in this scope
```

Probably an include is missing. You may try to add

```
 #include <string.h>
```

to the top of the file `src/thrifty.yy`

And report the bug to the http://incubator.apache.org/projects/thrift.html

Comment: Same error unfortunately.

Comment: Maybe try `./configure CXXFLAGS="-std=gnu++11"`. You can check `grep HAVE_STRDUP   config.h` after running ./configure. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573775/strdup-error-on-g-with-c0x